# How do I add data to an ArrayList of String data type

Tags: java, arraylist

This is just a simple problem that I challenged myself to solve: add names to an ArrayList. I think the problem has to do with the while loop I'm using to populate my ArrayList and the Scanner.

I've tried making two separate `Scanner` objects, but the loop still terminates when it shouldn't.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyArrayLiat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String finished = "n";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(finished == "n")
        {
            System.out.println("Enter data: ");
            myArrayList.add(keyboard.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Are you finished? y or n");
            finished = keyboard.nextLine();

        }
        System.out.println("myArrayList: " + myArrayList);

    }

}
```

```
Enter data: 
Trevor
Are you finished? y or n
n
myArrayList: [Trevor]
```

It should keep taking names until I type n, but it terminates after just the first name.

Comment: i think with input.nextLine() you receive the "\n". instead of `input.nextLine()` use `input.next()`,

Comment: yeah, so "finished" will be an empty string and the loop will terminate in any case. the question should not be marked as duplicate since the incorrect string comparison is not the only problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always use `equals` when comparing objects instead of `==`. Try `finished.equals(“n”)` in while condition